# Data isn't showing in datatable - PHP

Tags: php, jquery, datatables

I'm using  https://datatables.net for my Admin panel. I need help, When I try to display user data on the table it shows nothing. Everything is working in the Inspect, it just does not come out. Why?

Here is the code of **app-user-list.js**

```
  if (dtUserTable.length) {
    dtUserTable.DataTable({
        "ajax": {
            "url": assetPath + 'data/user-list.php',
            "type": "POST"
        }, // JSON file to add data
      columns: [
        // columns according to JSON
        { data: 'responsive_id' },
        { data: 'full_name' },
        { data: 'email' },
        { data: 'role' },
        { data: 'current_plan' },
        { data: 'status' },
        { data: '' }
      ],
      columnDefs: [
        {
          // For Responsive
          className: 'control',
          orderable: false,
          responsivePriority: 2,
          targets: 0
        },
        {
          // User full name and username
          targets: 1,
          responsivePriority: 4,
          render: function (data, type, full, meta) {
            var $name = full['full_name'],
              $uname = full['username'],
              $image = full['avatar'];
            if ($image) {
              // For Avatar image
              var $output =
                '<img src="' + assetPath + 'images/avatars/' + $image + '" alt="Avatar" height="32" width="32">';
            } else {
              // For Avatar badge
              var stateNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
              var states = ['success', 'danger', 'warning', 'info', 'dark', 'primary', 'secondary'];
              var $state = states[stateNum],
                $name = full['full_name'],
                $initials = $name.match(/\b\w/g) || [];
              $initials = (($initials.shift() || '') + ($initials.pop() || '')).toUpperCase();
              $output = '<span class="avatar-content">' + $initials + '</span>';
            }
            var colorClass = $image === '' ? ' bg-light-' + $state + ' ' : '';
            // Creates full output for row
            var $row_output =
              '<div class="d-flex justify-content-left align-items-center">' +
              '<div class="avatar-wrapper">' +
              '<div class="avatar ' +
              colorClass +
              ' mr-1">' +
              $output +
              '</div>' +
              '</div>' +
              '<div class="d-flex flex-column">' +
              '<a href="' +
              userView +
              '" class="user_name text-truncate"><span class="font-weight-bold">' +
              $name +
              '</span></a>' +
              '<small class="emp_post text-muted">@' +
              $uname +
              '</small>' +
              '</div>' +
              '</div>';
            return $row_output;
          }
        },
        {
          // User Role
          targets: 3,
          render: function (data, type, full, meta) {
            var $role = full['role'];
            var roleBadgeObj = {
              Subscriber: feather.icons['user'].toSvg({ class: 'font-medium-3 text-primary mr-50' }),
              Author: feather.icons['settings'].toSvg({ class: 'font-medium-3 text-warning mr-50' }),
              Maintainer: feather.icons['database'].toSvg({ class: 'font-medium-3 text-success mr-50' }),
              Editor: feather.icons['edit-2'].toSvg({ class: 'font-medium-3 text-info mr-50' }),
              Admin: feather.icons['slack'].toSvg({ class: 'font-medium-3 text-danger mr-50' })
            };
            return "<span class='text-truncate align-middle'>" + roleBadgeObj[$role] + $role + '</span>';
          }
        },
        {
          // User Status
          targets: 5,
          render: function (data, type, full, meta) {
            var $status = full['status'];

            return (
              '<span class="badge badge-pill ' +
              statusObj[$status].class +
              '" text-capitalized>' +
              statusObj[$status].title +
              '</span>'
            );
          }
        },
        {
          // Actions
          targets: -1,
          title: 'Actions',
          orderable: false,
          render: function (data, type, full, meta) {
            return (
              '<div class="btn-group">' +
              '<a class="btn btn-sm dropdown-toggle hide-arrow" data-toggle="dropdown">' +
              feather.icons['more-vertical'].toSvg({ class: 'font-small-4' }) +
              '</a>' +
              '<div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">' +
              '<a href="' +
              userView +
              '" class="dropdown-item">' +
              feather.icons['file-text'].toSvg({ class: 'font-small-4 mr-50' }) +
              'Details</a>' +
              '<a href="' +
              userEdit +
              '" class="dropdown-item">' +
              feather.icons['archive'].toSvg({ class: 'font-small-4 mr-50' }) +
              'Edit</a>' +
              '<a href="javascript:;" class="dropdown-item delete-record">' +
              feather.icons['trash-2'].toSvg({ class: 'font-small-4 mr-50' }) +
              'Delete</a></div>' +
              '</div>' +
              '</div>'
            );
          }
        }
      ],
      order: [[2, 'desc']],
      dom:
        '<"d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center header-actions mx-1 row mt-75"' +
        '<"col-lg-12 col-xl-6" l>' +
        '<"col-lg-12 col-xl-6 pl-xl-75 pl-0"<"dt-action-buttons text-xl-right text-lg-left text-md-right text-left d-flex align-items-center justify-content-lg-end align-items-center flex-sm-nowrap flex-wrap mr-1"<"mr-1"f>B>>' +
        '>t' +
        '<"d-flex justify-content-between mx-2 row mb-1"' +
        '<"col-sm-12 col-md-6"i>' +
        '<"col-sm-12 col-md-6"p>' +
        '>',
      language: {
        sLengthMenu: 'Show _MENU_',
        search: 'Search',
        searchPlaceholder: 'Search..'
      },
      // Buttons with Dropdown
      buttons: [
        {
          text: 'Add New User',
          className: 'add-new btn btn-primary mt-50',
          attr: {
            'data-toggle': 'modal',
            'data-target': '#modals-slide-in'
          },
          init: function (api, node, config) {
            $(node).removeClass('btn-secondary');
          }
        }
      ],
```

And more, but this is for table.

This is code in **Users/index.blade.php**

```
@section('title')
Users
@endsection

@section('content')

<!-- BEGIN: Content-->
<div class="app-content content ">
        <div class="content-overlay"></div>
        <div class="header-navbar-shadow"></div>
        <div class="content-wrapper">
            <div class="content-header row">
            </div>
            <div class="content-body">
                <!-- users list start -->
                <section class="app-user-list">
                    <!-- list section start -->
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-datatable table-responsive pt-0">
                            <table class="user-list-table table">
                                <thead class="thead-light">
                                    <tr>
                                        <th></th>
                                        <th>User</th>
                                        <th>Email</th>
                                        <th>Role</th>
                                        <th>Plan</th>
                                        <th>Status</th>
                                        <th>Actions</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                            </table>
                    </div>
                    <!-- list section end -->
                </section>
                <!-- users list ends -->

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- END: Content-->

@endsection
```

This is code in **data/user-list.php**

```
 
 /*
  * DataTables example server-side processing script.
  *
  * Please note that this script is intentionally extremely simple to show how
  * server-side processing can be implemented, and probably shouldn't be used as
  * the basis for a large complex system. It is suitable for simple use cases as
  * for learning.
  *
  * See http://datatables.net/usage/server-side for full details on the server-
  * side processing requirements of DataTables.
  *
  * @license MIT - http://datatables.net/license_mit
  */
  
 /* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
  * Easy set variables
  */
   
 // DB table to use
 $table = 'users';
  
 // Table's primary key
 $primaryKey = 'id';
  
 // Array of database columns which should be read and sent back to DataTables.
 // The `db` parameter represents the column name in the database, while the `dt`
 // parameter represents the DataTables column identifier. In this case object
 // parameter names
 $columns = array(
     array( 'db' => 'id', 'dt' => 'responsive_id' ),
     array( 'db' => 'id',  'dt' => 'id' ),
     array( 'db' => 'name',   'dt' => 'name' ),
     array( 'db' => 'lastname',     'dt' => 'full_name' ),
     array( 'db' => 'email',     'dt' => 'email' ),
     array( 'db' => 'birthday',     'dt' => 'current_plan' ),
     array( 'db' => 'gender',     'dt' => 'status' ),
     array( 'db' => 'image',     'dt' => 'avatar' ),
     array(
         'db'        => 'role',
         'dt'        => 'role',
     ),
     array(
         'db'        => 'name',
         'dt'        => 'username',
     )
 );
  
 // SQL server connection information
 $sql_details = array(
     'user' => 'root',
     'pass' => '',
     'db'   => 'family_space',
     'host' => '127.0.0.1'
 );
  
  
 /* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
  * If you just want to use the basic configuration for DataTables with PHP
  * server-side, there is no need to edit below this line.
  */
  
 require( 'ssp.class.php' );
  
 echo json_encode(
     SSP::simple( $_POST, $sql_details, $table, $primaryKey, $columns )
 );
```

This is photo:
[image]

I really need help. can I fix this?

Comment: Can you show us your JSON? (The screenshot crops out the most important part of the JSON structure, unfortunately). If your JSON is just an unnamed array `[ {...}, {...}, ...]`, then you need to use `dataSrc: ""` in your DataTables [ajax option](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.dataSrc#Examples). If your JSON has a named array `{ "mydata": [ {...}, {...}, ...] }`, then you need to use that name: `dataSrc: "mydata"`.

Comment: Also, please do not use screenshots if you can provide the formatted text of the data/error/code directly in the question. (Or, use a screenshot to show additional information which cannot be provided by plain text on its own). It is much easier to search text, copy/paste it into test code, etc. In your case, the screenshot helps, but the text of the JSON would be even more helpful.

Comment: If the page is stuck on "loading" then this suggests there may have been an error - so can you check the browser's console for error messages?

Comment: Sorry for my late reply, I've checked my console log. It shows 13 error, so I can't paste it here. Can we continue in personal conversation?

Comment: Oh, I fixed it. It was render error, I was trying to get status when in database had no status. Thank you for helping.

Comment: @B3K4, please could you show us how you managed to fix this issue as I'm equally facing the same problem. Thanks